# Can I turn off terminal case sensitivity

Tags: linux, terminal, filenames

As above can I turn Case Sensitivity off for terminal in linux?

Comment: As an aside: maybe learning to use [Tab completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_line_completion) helps you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Case sensitivity is not a property of the terminal. It's not even a property of the shell. When it comes to file names, it's a property of the filesystem: you can have a file called `foo` and a file called `FOO` in the same directory, and they're different files, just like a file called `foo` and a file called `bar` are different files. It's also a property of individual programs: for example `ls -a` and `ls -A` mean different things.

Unix generally uses lowercase all around anyway. So most of the time you just need to refrain from using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

When you mount external filesystems that some OSes treat as case-insensitive, you can control whether Linux should treat them as case-insensitive too, by specifying the right option when mounting (see the `mount(8)` manual page). I think this is usually done by default for `fat`, `hfs` and `ntfs`.

If you use zsh, you can configure it for case insensitive completion in various ways (for example, if you type `f` and there is no file called `f*` but a files called `FOOBAR` and `FOOBAZ`, the `f` would change to `FOOBA`). Run `compinstall` to configure the simpler aspects of case-insensitive completion, and read zsh tutorial or the reference manual to find more options.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not since filenames and programs then could be duplicates of eachother. The structure of Linux and the filesystem would not allow for proper execution.

For example if the `/bin` would contain `mv` and `MV`, executing `mv` would execute them both.